# Почему в слове "учёба" пишется буква Ё?

Tags: этимология

Возможные ответы:

1) Это отглагольные существительные. Но: учить - учёба, трещать - трещотка. В обоих случаях существительные образовались от глагола, но пишутся по-разному.

2) Нужно обеспечить одинаковое написание слов с этим суффиксом. Но: хворать - хвороба, злиться - злоба, жаловаться - жалоба, молиться - мольба, суффикс ОБ/Б, нет ни в одном случае суффикса с буквой Ё.

Это слово всегда писалось с буквой Ё? А когда буквы Ё не было, слово уже существовало? Когда оно появилось в языке?

Спасибо.

Comment: Буква Ё также и в слове *учёный.*

Answer (score 4, accepted):

> А когда буквы Ё не было, слово уже существовало? Когда оно появилось в
>   языке?

См. [***"Этимологический словарь современного русского языка"*** А.К. Шапошникова:](https://books.google.ru/books?id=RZ6KAQAAQBAJ&pg=PA469&dq=%22%D1%83%D1%87%D0%B5%D0%B1%D0%B0%22%20%D1%81%D0%BB%D0%BE%D0%B2%D0%B0%D1%80%D1%8C&hl=ru&sa=X&ved=0ahUKEwiK6qLOm8PKAhVH8XIKHb4-BfAQ6AEIPzAH#v=onepage&q=%22%D1%83%D1%87%D0%B5%D0%B1%D0%B0%22%20%D1%81%D0%BB%D0%BE%D0%B2%D0%B0%D1%80%D1%8C&f=false)

> ***Учёба*** -- учение, обучение.
>
> Должно было существовать в русском языке **до XV в.**, когда
>   отм.<ечено> производное прилаг. *учьбьныи*, ***учьбы военные***
>   отм.<ечено> в словаре **1731 г.**, ***учеба*** -- в словаре Даля.
>
> Собств.-рус. производное имя деятельности с суф. ***-ьба*** от основы
>   глаг. ***учити***.

Встречается слово ***учьба*** и в старинном воинском уставе **1715** года…

В вышедшем в **1847** году *"Словаре церковно-славянского и русского языка"* приведён ещё один вариант слова *учёба* -- ***учебъ*** (со значением *учение 'выучка'*). В словаре при этом слове стоит помета *"старое"*.

Но в говорах слово *учёба* (в разных написаниях) продолжало жить -- со значением, которое можно было бы сформулировать как "процесс ученья, сопровождаемый бессмысленной зубрёжкой, механическим заучиванием" (Кузнецова О.Д., статья "УЧЕБА -- УЧЕНИЕ" // журнал "Русская речь", 1975, № 5).  Писатель XIX века А.И. Левитов в очерке "Сельское учение" (1884) назвал слово *учёба* сельским: *[Дети] "терпеливо сидели в учительских избах и беспрекословно занимались, **как это характерно названо сельским народом**, учебой"*.

И у других писателей слово это в XIX веке употреблялось главным образом при передаче речи героев-крестьян. Лишь в самом конце XIX -- начале XX веков *учёба* начинает встречаться и в авторских текстах, замещая слово *учение*.

Есть и у Ленина:

> *Но материала-то для **учебы** так мало, что без обобщения его по всей России учиться решительно не на чем.*
>
> [В. И. Ленин. Что делать? Наболевшие вопросы нашего движения (1902)]

Окончательное же утверждение  слова *учёба* приходится на двадцатые -- тридцатые годы ХХ века, что хорошо видно [из материалов Нацкорпуса](http://search1.ruscorpora.ru/plot.xml?smoothing=3&stat=gr_created_&env=alpha&mycorp=&mysent=&mysize=&mysentsize=&mydocsize=&spd=&text=lexgramm&mode=main&sort=gr_tagging&lang=ru&nodia=1&parent1=0&level1=0&lex1=%F3%F7%B8%E1%E0&gramm1=&sem1=&sem-mod1=sem&sem-mod1=sem2&flags1=&m1=&parent2=0&level2=0&min2=1&max2=1&lex2=&gramm2=&sem2=&sem-mod2=sem&sem-mod2=sem2&flags2=&m2=):

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

А вот как писалось это слово в начале двадцатого века?..  Похоже на то, что с ***"о"*** (может, и не всегда с ***"о"***, но других примеров пока привести не могу).

См.:

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

===

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

===

Возможность написания в довоенные годы *учёбы* и с *"о"* (на месте *"ё"*) была отражена и [**в словаре Ушакова**](http://dic.academic.ru/dic.nsf/ushakov/1073674):

> УЧЁБА (или учоба)

Comment: Большое спасибо, slava,  у Вас, не ответ, а целое исследование получилось. Мне кажется,  окончательное написание  "учёба" как исключение утвердилось  в связи с особым положением этого слова: краткий гласный Ь стал писаться как "е", а потом его стали соотносить с чередованием е/ё, как в корне. Возможно,  влияние оказало слово "учебник", где как раз отражено это чередование.

Answer (score 2):

Не знаю уж, когда появилось это слово в языке, но оно относительно новое. А всегда было — "учение". Скорее всего, уже в советские времена появилось. Именно по аналогии со злобой, хворобой и жалобой. Слово "учение" осталось, но потеснилось. Возможно, и буква Ё оттуда, от учЕния.

*Сытое брюхо к учёбе глухо?!*

Comment: А как Вы думаете, различаются учёба и учение по смыслу и стилю? Зачем советским людям потребовалось новое слово "учёба"?

Comment: Учёба и обучение - две субъективных стороны организованного учебного процесса (со стороны учащегося и учителя). В понятии же "учение" субъективный момент не выражен, и его можно относить в равной мере к получению и к передаче знаний. Поэтому "учёба" дополняет понятие "учение".

Comment: Учение также книжное и многозначное слово, оно  может обозначать совокупность теоретических положений в какой-л. области знаний, система взглядов на что-л. Но учеба, скорее, не такое уж новое слово, например:— Ванюша, — сказала старуха, — поди-ка ляг спать… тебе и так надоела эта учеба… [Н. В. Успенский. Декалов (1862)].